# JSON- RPC no response

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

I'm trying to use jscon-rpc but I dont get any response. After installing geth and loading the rinkeby test net does the ethereum node start ? I used "localhost" as the IP and "8545" as the port number. Have I missed out on anything? Please help

String callGeth(String inputJSON)

{

HTTPClient http;
    http.begin("http://IP address of my PC(have geth running) :8545/");
    http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    int httpCode = http.POST(inputJSON);
    String JSONResult = http.getString();
    Serial.println(JSONResult);
    http.end();
    return JSONResult;

}

```
StaticJsonBuffer<1000> JSONbuffer;   
JsonObject& gethQueryJSON = JSONbuffer.createObject(); 
gethQueryJSON["jsonrpc"] = "2.0";
gethQueryJSON["method"] = "eth_call";
JsonArray&  gethQueryParams = gethQueryJSON.createNestedArray("params");
JsonObject& gethCallParams = JSONbuffer.createObject();
gethCallParams["to"] = "0xC2eafE628dB80634Fdd657965B38136Ec6F3338A";
gethCallParams["data"] = "0x9de4d683";
gethQueryParams.add(gethCallParams);
gethQueryParams.add("account3");
gethQueryJSON["id"] = 1;
String gethStringJSON;
gethQueryJSON.printTo(gethStringJSON);
Serial.println("First Geth query JSON message isLightTurnedOn function: ");
Serial.println(gethStringJSON);  
String gethResult = callGeth(gethStringJSON); 
Serial.println(gethResult);
```

Comment: Can you explain what "don't get any response" means? Does the connection time out? Do you get an error? If you try a different port, e.g. 9999, does the same thing happen or something different?

Comment: I dont get any result. I did try,I still get no response.

Comment: What programming language and environment are you using? The code kind of looks like it's for an Arduino, but surely you're not running `geth` on an Arduino?

Comment: I have geth installed on my PC. In the callGeth function the IP address used is the IP of the PC. Is it right ?

Comment: Your question says you used "localhost," which is not the IP address of your PC.

Comment: Yeah. Sorry.I forgot to edit that.

Comment: I personally won't try to help if I'm given false information like that. Hopefully others are more charitable.

Comment: Sorry. I'm new to this. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as already mentioned by @smarx make sur to enable `rpc` on your node. For example

```
--rpc --rpcaddr 'localhost' --rpcport 8545 --rpcapi 'personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner'
```

then regarding your python code I've publish a full working example for deploying and interacting with a smart contract using raw HTTP JSON-RPC requests. I am pretty sure you'll find helpful hints. Here is my post
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/38965/30452

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `--rpc` on the command line to enable it, as per https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#go.

Comment: I id that.Still no response

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to make the JSON-RPC request?

Comment: I've edited the question. I cant figure out whats wrong

Answer (score 1):

As per your reply. If you enabled rpc port. Then there might a chance of geth client is not mining.

If you want to post any thing. You should start mining. Your transactions in UTX or pending. By default geth will not start mining.

So add `--mine` as a option in geth.

Otherwise if your eth client is running you can connect attach via ipc or rpc url and port

> $> geth attach 127.0.01:8585
>
> geth> miner.start()

Then execute your code